# .tap() contents are never called in RxJS

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, rxjs

I am developing an application that sends images to Microsoft face API and gets back the Face Rectangle coordinates, that I can use to draw it on the original image. Here is the responsible part of the code (we have already received the API response, stored in `this.faceApiResponse: Observable<FaceRecognitionResponse>`:

```
        //API call
        this.faceApiResponse = this.faceRecognitionService.sendImage(...);

        //Drawing
        var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = this.imageString;

        img.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 650, img.height * 650/img.width);
          this.faceApiResponse.pipe(tap(face => {
              ctx.rect(face.faceRectangle.left * 650/img.width,
              face.faceRectangle.top * 650/img.width,
              face.faceRectangle.width * 650/img.width,
              face.faceRectangle.height * 650/img.width);
              ctx.strokeStyle="#00ff00";
              ctx.stroke();
              alert("Finished");
          })).subscribe(_ => console.log("Canvas populated with rectangles"));
        }
```

`ctx.drawImage` is called every time a new image is uploaded and it works perfectly, however the rectangle drawing part does not (that I have encapsulated in `pipe(tap())` since `this.faceApiResponse` is an `Observable`).

Here is a piece of the `face.model` as well:

```
export interface FaceRecognitionResponse {
  //other fields...
  faceRectangle: FaceRectangle;
}

interface FaceRectangle {
  top: number;
  left: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}
```

Surfing though similar problems, I realized that most of the times people do not `subscribe` to the piping result. Which I did, but it still did not help the issue. The version of rxjs used is 6.5.4.

**EDIT**: what I have figured out is that `face.faceRectangle` is `undefined`. Even when there is an API response and when it is displayed on the page through the data binding...

Comment: Why exactly could this be an issue? () => should set the block context to `this`.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong on how you're using it... the only thing that could make it not work is if `faceApiResponse` doesn't emit anything. I'm assuming you're not receiving the log "Canvas populated with rectangles"... this would mean that faceApiResponse is just not emitting any value. Is there something on the Network tab that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What turned out to be a problem is that the `faceApiReponse` is actually a **list** of `FaceRecognitionResponse`s. Consequently, when I tried to access a `faceRectangle` field, it failed. So here is how I solved it:

```
img.onload = () => {
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 650, img.height * 650/img.width);
          this.faceApiResponse.pipe(tap((faces: any) => {
              for (var face of faces) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(face.faceRectangle.left * 650/img.width,
                face.faceRectangle.top * 650/img.width,
                face.faceRectangle.width * 650/img.width,
                face.faceRectangle.height * 650/img.width);
                ctx.strokeStyle="#00ff00";
                ctx.stroke();
              }
          })).subscribe(_ => console.log("Canvas populated with rectangles"));
```